# Does Microsoft.TeamFoudationServer.Client.dll supports TFVC labels and workspaces

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs-sdk, tfvc

I was using earlier version of the dll which was  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client which had helped me get TFVC workspaces and Labels, In the new Dll Microsoft.TeamFoudationServer.Client.dll which is supported by VSTS do we have any options like workspace and labels for TFVC.
I want to create labels in TFVC using the dll

Answer (score 0):

In every version since 2005, Version Control mechanics are part of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll`, this is still the case in Visual Studio 2017.

So the direct answer to your question is, "no". Support for TFVC is not part of `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client.dll`. You can find the latest version of the [TFVC client as part of the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient nuget package here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient).